# Can i add flickr,imgur etc. up-loader for my WP upload media button?

Tags: uploads

I am using wordpress latest version.I don't want to upload media to my hosting server. So i want to upload media to other source like imgur,flickr etc. and i want to authorize this upload button to all my users like **stackexchange** img uploader in new post section.Please tell me how to do that with a plugin or without a plugin?

Comment: A starting point would be to overlook their API. Also to consider are their Terms of Service. They might not approve of you using their bandwidth like that. I am certain StackExchange has a partnership with imgur...

Comment: I don't know how stackexchange do that with imgur?

Comment: Stackexchange is not powered by WordPress so it wouldn't matter if you did. I suggest looking through their API as a starting point: https://api.imgur.com/